# why core_liquid_balance field not show at cleos get account?

Tags: cleos, rpc

when use http://api.oraclechain.io, core_liquid_balance field is missing

```
{
            "account_name" => "wangmingyuan",
          "head_block_num" => 12584842,
         "head_block_time" => "2018-08-23T07:00:16.000",
              "privileged" => false,
        "last_code_update" => "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                 "created" => "2018-06-25T07:34:54.000",
               "ram_quota" => 18029,
              "net_weight" => 2001,
              "cpu_weight" => 32001,
               "net_limit" => {
         "used" => 5595,
    "available" => 128876,
          "max" => 134471
},
               "cpu_limit" => {
         "used" => 98145,
    "available" => 0,
```

but when use http://mainnet.eoscalgary.io, core_liquid_balance show up

```
{
            "account_name" => "wangmingyuan",
          "head_block_num" => 12585130,
         "head_block_time" => "2018-08-23T07:02:51.000",
              "privileged" => false,
        "last_code_update" => "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                 "created" => "2018-06-25T07:34:54.000",
     "core_liquid_balance" => "3.3320 EOS",
               "ram_quota" => 18029,
              "net_weight" => 2001,
              "cpu_weight" => 32001,
               "net_limit" => {
```

what's the difference between the hosts?

Answer (score 1):

it's related to not compiling source code using EOS as core symbol.